# passing data between two foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, foreach, modal-dialog

I have 2 foreach loops:
the first foreach contains lines for call a modal window.

The second foreach is located inside a window modal, this loop containing data based on the ID selected by the first foreach.

My question: How can I test the value of ID in the condition that is located inside the second foreach?

1st foreach:

```
@foreach($skils $skil)
.....
data-id="{{skil->force_id}}"
data-target="#myModal" 
data-toggle="modal"
.....
@endforeach 


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal"......
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myId".....

@foreach($services $service)
@if(service->force_id ==myId )
.....
@endforeach
```

jquery:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function (){
....
$("#myId").text(_self.data('id'));
.....
)},
```

Comment: if i get it correctly, you want to pass the id inside the modal window?

Comment: yes, the modal window

Answer (score 0):

In the button for opening the modal:

```
<button  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#yourmodalid" data-id="{{skil->force_id}}"   type="button">
```

to get the value with jquery:

```
$('#your_modal_id').on('show.bs.modal',function (e) {
                var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
                $(e.currentTarget).find('#the_id_inside_modal"]').val(id);
});
```

Comment: BUT, how I can use the value of #the_id_inside_modal in the if statement?

Comment: use it to do what?

Comment: As I have said before I want to use the value of ID, exp : #the_id_inside_modal in a foreach loop inside of the window modal

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution on the following link: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-get-dynamic-data-in-bootstrap-modal?page=1